# application crush when fresco run on adt17

Tags: fresco

when I use Fresco frame and do method Fresco.initialize(this); it crush on android system 4.2.2. it won't crush on other system.

```
02-24 14:12:59.298 17984-17984/com.example.deti:push E/dalvikvm: Could not     find class     'com.facebook.drawee.backends.pipeline.PipelineDraweeControllerBuilderSupplier', referenced from method com.facebook.drawee.backends.pipeline.Fresco.initializeDrawee
```

02-24 14:12:59.306 17984-17984/com.example.deti:push E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.facebook.imagepipeline.core.ImagePipelineFactory
                                                                           at com.facebook.drawee.backends.pipeline.Fresco.initialize(Fresco.java:32)
                                                                           at com.example.deti.CustomApplication.onCreate(CustomApplication.java:48)
                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1070)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4701)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:171)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1453)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5468)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:936)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
                                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CustomApplication extends MultiDexApplication {

public static Context applicationContext;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    applicationContext = this;
    MultiDex.install(this);
    //创建默认的ImageLoader配置参数
    //腾讯bugly接入
    Fresco.initialize(this);
```

pay attention the parent class,when I change Application to MultiDexApplication，it runs correctly on system 4.2.2